# 'this' in setOnCllickListener method

Tags: android, android-studio

This is not the complete code, just the part where I have a question

I'm wondering if this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Is the same as this:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            button.setOnClickListener(new MainActivity());
        }
    }
```

Sorry if it feels like a stupid question, newbie here :)

Comment: No it is not the same ! Your second option will create the instance of your activity.

Comment: I'd say no. The first one is using an already created Activity, so no allocation is necessary. The second one is creating another instance of the activity. Most likely, the second code won't even work as the instance listening to the clicks is different from the one that has the button reference.

Comment: `new` will create a new instance of the activity `this` is the context of already created instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, absolutely not, because in the second case you are creating a new activity with no reference to the first one. 
Instead in the first case you are passing the reference of the current instance of the main activity. So go for the first one :-)

Answer (score 1):

When we use `this` or `getAplicationContext()` it means you are passing reference and when you use `new MainActivity()` means you are creating new object of same activity. In this first one is more reliable so use first one.